# python function for extra lines to print

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is the function example.

```
def testfun(self,total, count, fruitname):
    self.totalvalue = total + count
    print "fruitname"

 self.testfun(10,5,"apple")
```

output:

```
  apple
```

Now I i need to print extra fruit name using testfun

so when i call like this:

```
 self.testfun(10,5,"apple","orange")
```

Expected out:

```
apple
orange
```

Is it possible achieve above output using same function "testfun" or I need to write two different functions.

Why i am asking is i have big function i need to call twice and for second time calling i need to print one extra input .

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a `*args` argument to a function. This `*args` is a catch-all argument for everything specified after the first two.

```
>>> def foo(x, y, *args):
...    print(x, y)
...    for arg in args:
...        print(arg)
... 
>>> 
>>> foo(10, 5, 'apple')
(10, 5)
apple
>>> foo(10, 5, 'apple', 'orange')
(10, 5)
apple
orange
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/4909087) answer explains the concept in nice detail.